# Folders with random number appear on root C: drive

Tags: windows, windows-10

Recently, I've discovered a strange folder on my root C: drive (I'm currently using Windows 10 20H1). The name of the folder and its subfolders (see images below) are all random numbers, but their name has some similarities: 14-digit number and start with **4703**. I really don't know why these folders appear, but they are taking a lot of spaces (around **7.45 GB**).

**Parent folder on C drive**
[image: IMG:]

**Subfolders**
[image: IMG:]

I also found out that they contain many system files and system apps (Internet Explorer, Windows Defender, Windows theme,...). They seem like a backup of my OS folders but literally, I have never backup my PC yet (I only use System Restore, with the maximum disk space allowed for restore points is 3.5 GB).

Why did these folders created? Is it safe to delete them?

Comment: This is likely Windows Update doing its thing.

Comment: @LPChip I don't really think so. There are many subfolders that also appear to be the same as other main folders in C: (like Program Files, Program Files (x86), ...). I guess so since I found many files that are part of system apps (Internet Explorer, Windows Defender, Windows Fax,...). I also noticed that there's a folder which doesn't have a random name is "ModifiableWindowsApp" (And this folder actually also appear in Program Files folder)

Comment: It seems that Windows 10 "2004", or "20H1", has broken a lot of things on some machines, the ability to start afresh while keeping your personal files and programs intact being one of them, so maybe on your PC, to prevent this from happening, the upgrade *did* create a backup of your personal files and programs in case things went south.

Comment: @Didier That may be the reason. It's true that some programs weren't working properly after I upgraded to Windows 10 20H1. A folder called "Windows.old" was also created after the upgrade to backup old system files and folders. I deleted that folder (as I don't actually have many personal files on my PC, mostly saved in cloud), and then that strange folder appeared two days later.

Comment: @Didier And btw, should I delete that folder?

Comment: If your programs work properly now, and if all your personal files are accounted for, and your old settings still in place, you can delete them, but you may have to take ownershiph of them first. I haven't "graduated" to 2004 yet, not sure I want to, to be honest, given all the crop I hear about this so-called upgrade, so I couldn't tell you if those folders are user-owned (doubtful) or system-owned.